# The correct way to use set builder notation of this set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is this the correct way to represent this set using this set builder notation?

$$\big\{1, 4, 9, 16, ..., 100\} \cap \big\{1, 3, 5, 7, ...\}$$

$$A=\big\{2x - 1 \wedge y^2 \; | \; x \in \mathbb{N}, y \in \mathbb{N}, x \leq 10\}$$

I am confused as to how to set one variable to describe an infinite range and another to describe a finite one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $\wedge$ operator is from logic and applies to propositions or boolean variables, but doesn't apply to numbers.

Either you use the existential quantifier, as in $$\{n\in \mathbb{N}\ |\ (\exists k\in\mathbb{N},(n=k^2)\wedge(k\leq10))\wedge (\exists \ell\in\mathbb{N},n=2\ell-1)\}$$

Or you can use the fact that the square of an integer is odd if and only if that integer is odd:

$$\{(2n-1)^2\ |\ n\in\mathbb{N},n\leq5\}$$

Comment: Doesn't your second set only square the odd numbers? And it doesn't include the odd number set

Comment: @ALKI You only want to square the odd numbers, since $\cap$ takes the intersection of two sets. Perhaps you are confusing $\cap$ with $\cup$?

Comment: @ALKI you are correct, but your set contains only squares of odd numbers anyway.

Comment: Ah I was confusing $\cap$ with $\cup$. Thank you